# python-wnck : Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installable

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install this, but have errors.

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-wnck' instead of './python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-3_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-wnck : Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```